# Mac OS X restore files deleted by git rm

Tags: git, restore, rm

i just messed up big. The way it happened is so emberassing that I won't write it down :)

So here's my problem:

- Github Repop deleted
- Local repo files delete by `git rm -r`
- Local repo new initalized

Is there any chance how to restore my data? Luckily it's in a very very early stage of this project.

Regards

Comment: All you did was `git rm -r` ? The repo is still there right?

Comment: What do you mean by "Local repo new initialized"?

Answer (score 3):

```
git reset HEAD
```

If you don't have any uncommited changes you care about then use

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I completely understand the state of your local repo, but if all you did was a `git rm -r *` and committed that, then everything is still there. You can just reset to the previous commit:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Comment: When I do this I only get the files which are excluded via .gitignore

Comment: That should not be the case. Did you make multiple commits after removing everything? You might have to reset back farther.