# Mac Eclipse Git Repositories - deleted everything

Tags: eclipse, git

I have lost all my work - I am crying

I used Eclipse Git Repositories, and deleted just the git(from Eclipse Git Repository Explore) and it totally deleted everything, everything, everything....?

Any help is really really appreciated.

I dont even have a terminal..... it ia all gone

Thanks in advance

I am sooooooo happy, I found the .git in the Terminal and did what "dunni" suggested(accepted it as the solution). Everybody, thank you - I totally panicked.

Comment: Do you own the hard drive it was saved on?  If it is a regular non SSD drive then I'd power it down, and mount it as read-only slave before your operating system writes over the place where it was.  You may be able to get bits and pieces of it back if it was hard deleted.  Describe exactly what you did to delete it.

Comment: You say you're on a Mac - don't you have Time Machine backups? Are you sure you deleted your `.git` folder? Maybe you just disabled `git` nature of the project. Try `ls -Al` standing on the project's root via Terminal.

Comment: If you did a `git rm -r` then this question is a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183106/mac-os-x-restore-files-deleted-by-git-rm

Comment: Thank you for replying - I have not even the workspace folder. I did it only from within Eclipse Git Repositor, not from the terminal, wich  I should have. I have a backup from 2 month back, I thought I would be safe with git, but I did Eclipse did something. I am............

Comment: You accidentally WHAT the entire workspace folder?  Your second sentence needs at least one adjective to make sense.  First step is to calm down and don't panic, it just makes it less likely you'll get your stuff back.

Comment: Right, sorry - I need to breath. Just add to the question. I can get to the workspace folder from the terminal and do a git status.

Comment: First, what kind of monitary loss are we talking about?  hundreds of dollars worth?  hundreds of thousands of dollars worth?  If it's worth an arm and a leg, it may behoove you to power down the hard drive it's on and take it to a data recovery specialist.

Comment: A professional hard drive data recovery specialist will cost you in the thousands, so we need to know how much this data is worth to you.

Comment: about 15000 usd... Thank you all, I have to talk to somebody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If git status still states "changes to be committed" and all your missing files are listed there, then you can redo your deletion with the command

```
git reset --hard
```

This will reset your working directory to the last commit in the master branch.
However, if you had uncommitted work in your working directory, this work is lost, but i think, this is a minor issue compared to a total loss.